# Two while Loop Statements showing different results

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new to python and struggling with 2 simple sets of code in which there is while loop used with a little difference (atleast in my opinion). These code should print 'i' while it is less than 6 but one set of code is printing '1 2 3 4 5 6' and the other is printing '0 1 2 3 4 5'. I'm not sure why there is the difference. Any help will be much appreciated. Code is below:

this code is printing: '1 2 3 4 5 6':

```
i=0
while i<6:
 i+=1
 print(i)
```

this code is printing: '0 1 2 3 4 5':

```
i=0
while i<6:
 print(i)
 i+=1
```

Comment: in the first loop, you just iterated 'i" before printing its value. That's why it starts printing 1.

Comment: In the first code you increment the number **before** printing, thus printing a too high number.

Comment: This just tells you how precise you need to be to write code in an imperative style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you are incrementing `i` before you print the value:

[image]

In the second example, however, you print the value of `i` first, and then increment it. That means, in the very first iteration, `0` is printed first instead of 1. Similarly, the last iteration will print a `5` since the value of `i` is incremented to `6` afterwards, and the while loop breaks.

[image]

Hopefully this helped! Please let me know if you have any further questions or need any clarification :)

Comment: This really cleared up the confusion. I appreciate it.

Comment: np! sorry if the drawing was a little messy i was on trackpad haha

Answer (score 0):

The magic you are seeing is because of `i+=1`

This is essentially the same as `i = i + 1`

In English that says "Make `i` to be equal whatever `i` is right now plus 1"